# Anti Alias, UIImage and Performance

Tags: ios, performance, uiimageview, uiimage, antialiasing

I have a `UIImage` loaded into a `UIImageView`. The `UIImage` is larger than the `UIImageView` and it has been scaled down to fit. Obviously the scaled down `UIImage` shows jagged edges.

**What is the best way to anti-alias this image with regards to performance?**

I've seen [this method using `drawInRect`](http://d3signerd.com/old/image-anti-aliasing-in-objective-c/) but [I've also read that `drawInRect` does not give the best performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14668271/1037617).

I've read several different articles and I've tried a few methods myself. But after reading a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838975/1037617) [more](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1708/_index.html) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767609/1037617) on the performance differences between using `UIViews` and Core Graphics, I was wondering which method for anti aliasing an image gives the best performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Investigate the list of available [Core Image Filters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CILanczosScaleTransform). Specifically, the Lanczos Scale Transform available via `CILanczosScaleTransform` seems to be exactly what you need. It should be available on all iOS versions >= 6.0.

Typically, using Core Image filters will be more performant than manually resorting to Core Graphics. However, I urge you to verify the results as well as the performance in your specific case.

Comment: Hi this works great on larger images, but my smaller images are really blurry - Im looking into `CIUnsharpMask`, but is there a way to use `CILanczosScaleTransform` without it blurring the images?

Comment: Well, the Lanczos scale transform is typically only meant to be used to scale down an image and still get a high quality result. You can detect when your images are sufficiently larger than the image view and only conditionally apply the filter. Of course, for images lacking sufficient detail, certain blurriness while upscaling in inescapable.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is always having the right image size in your `UIImageView`. However, if you cannot have the correct image size and you need to resize it, another good solution is to use CoreGraphics to perform an image scale operation outside the main thread.

Since SDK 4.0, [CoreGraphics operations are thread safe](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/drawing-on-uiimages/), so you can put all the resizing stuff into a background queue and handle the resizing in there. Once the resizing has finished, you have to assign the cropped image in your `UIImageView` in the main thread because all `UIKit` stuff must be done in that thread. With this approach, you're not going to block the main thread every time you resize the images.

Once you've done that, you can also cache the cropping results in order to avoid repetitive cropping calculation (i.e., every time you scroll into the same `UITableViewCell`) and improve performance.

You can implement this as a `UIImage` category, take my code as an example:

```
- (void)resizeImageWithSize:(CGSize)size
                   cacheKey:(NSString *)cacheKey
            completionBlock:(void (^)(UIImage *croppedImage))completionBlock
{
    dispatch_async([[self class] sharedBackgroundQueue], ^{
        // Check if we have the image cached
        UIImage *resizedImage = [[[self class] resizedImageCache] objectForKey:cacheKey];
        if (nil == resizedImage) {
            // If not, resize and cache it
            @autoreleasepool {
               resizedImage = [self resizeImageWithSize:size];
               [[[self class] resizedImageCache] setObject:resizedImage forKey:cacheKey];
            }
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionBlock(resizedImage);
        });
    });
}
```

Then, the `resizeImageWithSize:` method implementation is the one where all CoreGraphics stuff happen. You may find interesting the [FXImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXImageView) library by Nick Lockwood, which uses the same approach: `UIImageView` category, has a resize cache and uses a background thread to do the Core Graphics stuff.

Comment: Thanks for this, do you have a copy of this code in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked about Swift in the comments:

[Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) has all of this built in, including an automatic caching layer. If you're not using this for network requests, at the very least it's a great example to work from.

Example:

```
// Note: this seamlessly handles both scaling AND caching the scaled image
let filter = AspectScaledToFillSizeFilter(size: imageView.frame)
imageView.af_setImage(withURL: url, filter: filter)
```

Just make sure `imageView.frame` is set beforehand (e.g. call `layoutIfNeeded()` first for autolayout) or it'll assert.

Comment: Wtf, this should be in a big info box right on top of the Alamofire Readme File :D – thank you!